# Add authors name along with their affiliations in word document in Rmarkdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown

My intention is to produce the following **word document** in Rmarkdown.
[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

yaml metadata has provision for author and address.